# Restrict github merge type by source branch

Tags: github

By default, github allows you to squash, merge or rebase when merging a PR.
Is it possible to conditionally restrict the allowed merge types?

In our team, we typically squash PRs onto our feature (or develop) branches.
However, when merging feature branches back into develop (or develop -> feat/*) we want to use a merge commit.

It is straightforward enough to choose the correct button in the github UI, be we occasionally have someone choose the wrong option by mistake and need to repair the repo afterwards.

Is there any way to restrict the allowed options in github?
This could either by branch name (e.g. merging from feat/* or develop must be a merge)?